# nfc ndefformatable ioexception format

Tags: format, nfc, ioexception, ndef

I have a similar problem when I want to format an `unformatted` tag. I am in Android 6. I have a proprietary device in Android 4.4 and the same code works well. Here is the code that I use and I send you the information of my tag.

```
public static void writeToTag(Tag paramTag, final NdefMessage paramNdefMessage) throws Exception
{
    List localList = Arrays.asList(paramTag.getTechList());
    if (localList.contains(NFC_TECH_NDEF)) {
        Ndef localNdef = Ndef.get(paramTag);
        localNdef.connect();
        if (localNdef.getMaxSize() < paramNdefMessage.toByteArray().length) {
            throw new E_TagTooSmallException();
        }
        localNdef.writeNdefMessage(paramNdefMessage);
        localNdef.close();
        return;
    }
    if (localList.contains(NFCTECH_NDEF_FORMATTABLE)) { //my Tag is NDefFormatable 
        NdefFormatable localNdefFormatable = NdefFormatable.get(paramTag);
        localNdefFormatable.connect(); // OK
        try {
            localNdefFormatable.format(paramNdefMessage); //IO Exception here
        } finally {
            localNdefFormatable.close();
        }
        return;
    }
    throw new Exception("Tag is unsupported");
}
```

[image: NFC Tools report Tag]

Thank you for your help !!

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking.  Are you getting an error?  Where?

Comment: According to the comment, it looks like there's an IOException being thrown by `localNdefFormatable.format(paramNdefMessage);`. @DavidM, could you post the stack trace, too.

Comment: did you manage to make it work? you could add the solution if so...